# How to integrate your power automated flow to your bot?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I have created a power automated flow which will be triggered when ever i receive an outlook mail. Can i integrate this flow to a bot that i have created and deployed to Microsoft teams?
I want the response of this flow to be a response of the bot that i have created.

Comment: Flow Bot itself works as a Bot inside teams. Could you please share the detailed scenario here? Do you want to give the output from Flow Bot as a input to the Bot you have in Teams?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Yes, i want the bot that i have deployed in teams to be the one telling the user that you have so n so notification

Comment: A Bot's output cannot be another Bot's input. If you want your Bot to able to read the notification you might have to use the[ Activity feed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/activity-feed-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) API and return a message to the user.

Comment: But i saw this documentation where it says that you can "Use a Microsoft Bot Framework bot with Power Virtual Agents"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-virtual-agents/advanced-use-dispatcher.
But `dotnet run -p ContentConverter.csproj -c Release -- -i <path to msdynce_botcontents.csv> -c <path to annotations.csv> -b <your bot id>
` command is throwing error saying its of wrong syntax